# Compiler error about IGradientOptions using setGradient on a fabric Object

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I am working on an Angular project and I am using the canvas class of the fabric.js library to create a circle with a gradient fill.

The problem is in the syntax when using the setGradient function of the fabric.Oject. I tried 2 ways: 1) the way defined in fabric-impl.d.ts but that doesn't work (I get an empty shape). On the other hand using it as shown in the [documentation example](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#setGradient), does work but produces a compiler error.

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1) Create a new project using the CLI (`ng new`)
>
> 2) Install fabric using npm (`nmp install fabric`)
>
> 3) Install fabric types using npm (`npm install @types/fabric`)
>
> 4) Create a Canvas, create a circle and try to use `setGradient` on that
>   object

#### Create canvas and circle object

```
        let nWidth:number = 300;
        let nHeight:number = 300;

        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', <any>{width: nWidth, height: nHeight, hoverCursor: 'auto'});
        let options: fabric.IObjectOptions = { left: 0, top: 0, originX: "left", originY: "top", objectCaching: false, selectable: false};      
        let circle: fabric.Circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 150, fill: 'Blue', ...options});
```

#### setGradient as defined in IGradientOptions

This does not work (empty shape) but does not produce any errors in the compiler.

```
circle.setGradient('fill', {
            type: 'linear',
            coords:{
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: circle.width,
            y2: circle.height
            },
            colorStops: {
              0: "#0000FF",
              1: "#FF0000"
            }
          });
```

#### setGradient as shown in documentation

This does work but produces the error shown below. The only difference here is that coords are passed directly instead of the "coords" option.

```
        circle.setGradient('fill', {
            type: 'linear',
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: circle.width,
            y2: circle.height,
            colorStops: {
              0: "#0000FF",
              1: "#FF0000"
            }
          });
```

#### The error for the second setGradient method

```
 ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(26,4): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: string; x1: number; y1: number; x2: number; y2: number; colorStops: { 0: string; 1: string; };
}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGradientOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x1' does not exist in type 'IGradientOptions'.
```

I am a beginner with typescript and angular and this is just a guess, but it seems to me like this is a conflict between the actual fabric module that expects things one way and the fabric types which are defined differently. I checked my package.json file and this is what I have for fabric after install:

```
"@types/fabric": "^3.0.0",
"fabric": "^3.2.0",
```

I tried installing fabric 3.0.0 to match the types version but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, this has been up for some time and no response so I will just post my workaround, though its not the preferred solution.

So I just edited the IGradientOptions interface in my fabric-impl.d.ts file to reflect the structure expected by fabric.js. This way the compiler error is gone and the code works as well.

The only issue then is that I would have to do that every time I use "npm install" since the file will be re downloaded to its original form. But well, its not something you do very often and I suppose it will be fixed in some update of the types file in the near future.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. The solution is to fork the typescript repo and push the changes. Then use the following to update your packages:

`npm install <ghusername>/<repoName>`, where `<ghUsername>` is your GitHub username (without the @) and `<repoName>` is the name of the repository. That should correctly install it. You will most likely want to use the --save or --save-dev flag with the install command to save dependency in your package.json.

In case you want to fix it for the community, you can submit a merge request with the fix and a version bump.